# Centering and evenly spacing multiple objects in Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

For a new game I'm making, I need to have 3 rectangles centered and evenly spaced apart along the bottom of the canvas, but I need to be able to add more rectangles, and have them evenly spaced as well, (probably no more than 5 though)

I started by just taking the width of the canvas, dividing it by (NumberOfBoxes), and setting the x to that plus half the width, but this results in them having a bigger gap between the right wall and the right-most box, than the left wall and the left-most box.

```
class Box {   
constructor(game, x){     
this.game = game;     
this.width = 150;     
this.height = 75;     
this.x = this.game.width/this.game.numberOfBoxes*x;     
this.y = this.game.height - this.height;   
}  

draw(context){     
context.fillRect(this.x + this.width/2, this.y, this.width, this.height); 
}
```

(the x being pulled in is the variable telling each box which fraction of the canvas to sit in)

I also tried using mod to get the remaining space after the boxes, then adding part to each box's x-pos, but this also did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here is to first calculate the total width of the empty area in between the rectangles and the border of the canvas itself.

This is done by multiplying the number of rectangles by it's width and subtracting the result from the canvas' width.

`((canvas.width - boxesWidth * numberOfBoxes)`

To get the actual gap, we need to divide this number by the number of rectangles **+1** - this is important.

`let gap = ((canvas.width - boxesWidth * numberOfBoxes) / (numberOfBoxes + 1));`

Now it's just a matter of incrementing the screen position by gap + the width of a rectangle and draw the rectangles accordingly.

Here's an example:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
let context = canvas.getContext("2d");

let boxesWidth = 35;

function draw() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  let numberOfBoxes = parseInt(document.getElementById("slider").value);
  let gap = ((canvas.width - boxesWidth * numberOfBoxes) / (numberOfBoxes + 1));
  let x = gap;
  for (let a = 0; a < numberOfBoxes; a++) {
    context.fillRect(x, 50, boxesWidth, 15);
    x += gap + boxesWidth;
  }
}

document.getElementById("slider").oninput = function() {
  draw();
}

draw();
```

```css
canvas {
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas><br>
<input type="range" min=1 max=7 value=3 id="slider">
```

Comment: This was very helpful, thanks!